# an error in gradle file Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

Tags: android

hello im getting this error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
and i dont know the cause please help
 gradle file

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.oumnia.advalio"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
   // compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3"


}
```

thanks.

Comment: Check this link to see more about your problem and how you can fix it https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html . But, please consider not using the full `play-services` version and use only the things you need https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: Can u  please explain to me what is the problem i tried all the solutions nothing works.Thanks

Comment: Your apk has more than 64k methods and this is not supported by `Dalvik`. The count is done by adding Android framework methods, library methods and your methods. Having a simple look, you can see that, if a library has too many methods it will impact your apk methods number and raise the error. In your case, the main problem is the `play-services`, because it has a lot of functionality in it (from login to google maps, ads and so on). To fix this, try to import only what you need (just `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1` for maps). What do you use from `play-services`?

Comment: i use it for maps and location.thanks

Comment: No problem! If the problem isn't fix, feel free to reply

Comment: i add just  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
              compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0' ans i still have the same problem

Comment: i figure out that compile project(':httpcore-4.2.3') is  the problem how can i resolve the problem now .Thanks

Comment: I don't know what they contain, but maybe you can use only volley and remove them